# How to provision multiple ALBs in one terraform deployment?

Tags: terraform, amazon-emr, terraform-provider-aws, aws-application-load-balancer

We want to increase number of EMR clusters as per requirements, and integrate those clusters with AWS-ALBs (Application Load Balancers)

We are thinking of provisioning multiple AWS-ALBs during a Terraform deployment, and then integrate those EMR clusters with ALBs, Where use-case also involves resiliency towards Create/Update and Delete of EMR clusters.

Any idea how to solve this use-case in best possible way , ie,

1. How do we provision multiple alb instances in one Terraform deploy ?
2. How should we integrate those ALBs to EMR clusters in best possible way ?

Comment: I am not expecting code, just some help and direction would work, Since I myself am not too good at Tf, I am unable to provide any TF code or minimum reproducible example.

Comment: Are you saying you want an ALB per EMR cluster? What's the point of the ALB here?

Comment: Define multiple ALB resources in your terraform code. Or define a single ALB resource with a `for_each`. Your question is so vague. Do it the same way you define multiple of **anything** in Terraform. What exactly are you stuck on?

Comment: So the use-case is that I might have 100 EMR clusters, now there is a limit to number of emr clusters I can attach to a particular ALB. Thus to scale it up, suppose I have 5 ALBs, I can connect 20 emr clusters each one of them thus effectively scaling even with the limitation.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR There are multiple applications inside my clusters whose web interfaces I have to expose, thus those services need to be connected to ALBs

Comment: @MarkB to be honest the terraform "terraform-aws-alb" doesn't have count like we had in s3 and other modules, where I can specify number of instances I want. I did explore the idea of for_each, and the issue with that is how do I tap into cluster info, to get a appropriate number of iterations that I should do so as to provide just the minimum number of resources and not overcreate